# SQL ACCESS query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was given a task to count how many times in the changelog table a given value occurs in the ean3 column and then show these values where their number of occurrences is greater than b.quantity / divisor from the pz40 table)

In the pz40 table there is a column b_eanvbn which has the same values, but there are many more of them, and here is only an example of whether it is a good one.

```
SELECT n.INDEX, n.EAN3, COUNT(n.EAN3) AS liczba_wystapien_noteszmian
FROM noteszmian AS n
INNER JOIN pz40 AS p ON n.INDEKS = p.b_indeks
WHERE n.EAN3 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY n.INDEKS, n.EAN3
HAVING COUNT(n.ean3) > (p.b_ilosc / p.dzielnik);

SELECT b_eanvbn, COUNT() AS liczba_wystapien
FROM pz40
WHERE b_eanvbn IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY b_eanvbn
HAVING COUNT() > (SUM(b_ilosc) / SUM(dzielnik));
```

these are my ideas, but I keep getting the error below

The query does not include the specified expression COUNT(n.ean3) > (p.b_ilosc/p.divisor) as an element of the aggregate function

Comment: Is the field name INDEX or INDEKS? Try: `HAVING COUNT() > (SUM(b_ilosc) / SUM(dzielnik)) = True`.

Comment: indeks  - Polish equivalent

Comment: Yes, but why both in query?

Comment: true, my mistake, I didn't see it,thanks

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: No ,it still doesnt work ,just the way I want it

Comment: Suggest you provide sample data as well as desired result as formatted text tables.

Comment: The second SQL needs asterisk or field name in the Count() function.